# lost my moto e phone without sim card

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I had bought a MOTO E which was stolen the very next day but, due to some issues, I had already taken my sim and the sdcard out. Is there any way I can locate my phone using the google id I had used to start the tracking features?

Answer (score 0):

If your Moto E has Android Device Manager enabled and the WiFi is connected to network, then you're in luck!

Also, file a police report **immediately** and tell them that you phone was stolen. That is my two cents on this answer.

Answer (score 0):

only if the device has any anti virus software installed with **anti-theft** feature or **Android Device Manager** enabled.